# How to do MSBuild's GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

In MSBuild, there's the `GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove` function that finds the first ancestor directory that includes certain file.

For those not familiar with that MSBuild function, here's an example.

I have a file:

`c:\projects\root.txt`

I want to be able to run a script such as:

`c:\projects\everything\foo\bar\myscript.cmd`

And would like to find `c:\projects\`, since it's the closest ancestor to `c:\projects\everything\foo\bar\` that has that file in it. The script should also be able to detect when the files is not present in any of the ancestors and just get an empty string.

How do I achieve the same in a (Windows) batch script?

Comment: You mean the parent directory of a file? `for %%J in ("\path\to\your\file.txt") do for %%I in ("%~dpJ.") do echo %%~nxI` (if you try this directly in command prompt, replace every `%%` by `%`)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how that works with examples?

Comment: Just edited the question with an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "theFile=%~1"

rem Get the path of this Batch file, i.e. "c:\projects\everything\foo\bar\"
set "myPath=%~DP0"

rem Process it as a series of ancestor directories
rem i.e. "c:\" "c:\projects\" "c:\projects\everything\" etc...
rem and search the file in each ancestor, taking as result the last one

set "result="
set "thisParent="
set "myPath=%myPath:~0,-1%"
for %%a in ("%myPath:\=" "%") do (
   set "thisParent=!thisParent!%%~a\"
   if exist "!thisParent!%theFile%" set "result=!thisParent!"
)

if defined result (
   echo %result%
) else (
   echo There is not such file in my ancestors
)
```

Put the name of the file as parameter of this Batch file. For example, if you name this file `GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove.bat`, you may use it this way:

```
GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove root.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I can name that tune in 2 (long lines). The code is short. The explanation is long.

```
@rem will search up to 8 levels up from here
@Set Ancestry=.;..;..\..;..\..\..;..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..;..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..;
@REM %~dp$Ancestry:1 -- search paths in Ancestry for arg 1
@REM finds files of any type, not just exe
@REM LocalTop is either the folder where arg 1 (%1) was found or empty
@Set LocalTop=%~dp$Ancestry:1
```

How it works:

1. Ancestry is a series of places to look: . then .., then .... and so on. I stopped at 8 levels. Add more, although I have never needed more levels.
2. The next line uses the magic of cmd. Note this only syntax works for %0..%9 or in a for statement with the for variable.

From FOR /?:

```
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

What was not obvious to me, is that it is not limited to the environment variable 'PATH'. You may supply any variable, which is what Ancestry is above.